# App Rejection twice due to crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, crash, app-store

I have a iOS app built in swift. I had successfully passed the review the first time. Yesterday while providing an update, I got my rejection due to "Crash on Launch". I have the following symbolised crash logs, I am trying to analyse it, and for most of the part i can say its the issue with did finish on launching. I still am timid about the issue.

What is the actual issue of the crash as per the logs and how can i solve this?

Following are 2 crash logs :

The crash Logs -

[Log 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ea63xvdqlq0onc1/crashlog-343B5F50-96E3-4115-A091-202742E41E49.crash?dl=0)

[Log 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vstq1m67eugerbx/crashlog-511F40B4-43B8-4B6C-8581-7F5E6DC7E4D6.crash?dl=0)

Following is `didFinishLaunching` at the time on 1st submission, This was accepted :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    #if DEVELOPMENT
        print("Development Mode Started")
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
        guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            else {
                fatalError("Couldn't load config file")
        }
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    #else
        print("Production Mode Started")
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    #endif


    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Appsee.self])

    let uid = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID)

    if uid != nil {
        checkforAccess()
    }

    return true
}
```

and while this was in the `didFinishLaunchin`, I had another observer at another view which was initialVC. that also simultaneously was checking for the presence of a user and if not will present the 'BootVC' which was similar to the above method in AppDelegate.

I realised and have removed this, But my concern here is, Is there any other information in the logs that i am missing.

P.S : I ran the app in a fresh environment on a totally new device with a beta software. There were no crashes, both then and now.

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Please let me know if more information is required. I will be prompt.

Comment: Would be better add did finish on launching code? By the way i did not down vote your question

Let us know, what you have done  while launching?

Comment: updated my question, Thanks for the response

Comment: is there any  code changes in app delegate with previous version what u have uploaded in itunes? did you get log from crashlystics?

Comment: I have edited my question. Also, The `checkforAccess()` is same. I majorly think they may not be able to go past through the login since its needs a facial verification and upon whose completion a access token is generated, which they won't be having.

Comment: also add checkfor access method. Is there any navigaion code?

Comment: and that might be the issue they would have been logged out. But the issue of crashing is really alien to me.

Comment: assumption, you are removing user id from key chain and user  still having your app in his device then your uploading new version to store, then user tries to update it(here u did if user get id, u did just saving id in keychain).Is there any navigaion code in checkaccess method?

Comment: if your user id is nil, it wont redirect right

Comment: I am not quite clear. Are you asking If I still have the user after removing the  user Id from keychain. I actually check for the access tokens, and if not the user is logged out and all the app data is deleted for a fresh person to use it. Am i being clear here

Comment: Thats right it won't redirect

Comment: May i know your login functionality? Why are you getting user id from firebase? where is login happening? i am not good at english, pls adjust

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log in order to determine on which line your app crashed

Comment: its already done. Its in the link itself. As I said I am not able to clearly understand what its states. I will edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the logs that you have provided to give more meaningful information.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with the logs. Can You help me find the issue now. Again, as far as I see, the crash is due to the 'didFinishWithLaunching` and the case i explained.

Comment: As others have said, "Symbolicate the crash log".  You need to know what "7   SpotMi 0x000000010045fd78 0x10032c000 + 1260920" translates to as a code symbol.  (Maybe "19  SpotMi 0x0000000100333e14 0x10032c000 + 32276" also.)

Comment: I decoded it. Got the issue. It was in my realm allocation. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @AakashDave have you checked my answer ? see if its useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As initial level your issue looks very uncleared. Also crash logs not defining exact issue.

**Possible issues :**

> - Check if the crash issue happens only on arm 64 devices. If so than you should check if your app is enable for the base 64 support & if
>     not than provide support
> - Another reason is if your app accessing privacy sensitive data such as location tracking or accessing photo library or something like
>     without permission than also it will get closed at the launch time

**To get resolve :**

> - To simply get accurate crash reports use crashlytics tool inside your app. It will help you to find the line on which crash occurs
> - Another common way is to try & test app on debug environment & enable exception break points

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! Well, The app passed the review. Also, I had crashalytics installed in the app, it was somehow not working. The main reason I found for this crash was realm being initialised at the very start of the app which was preventing the firebase to initialise, which resulted in nil values. I ended up creating a singleton class for the realm and initialised it. And yes, The exception breakpoints did help in debugging it later. Cheers to you mate!

Comment: @AakashDave good to see you resolved your issue...+1 for your efforts...